# Почему не происходят изменения объекта?

Tags: javascript, объекты, prototype

Насколько я знаю, объекты присваиваются по ссылке (!не копируются). Поэтому если изменения в объекте происходят по одной ссылке, то они происходят и по другой.

```js
let a = {
  writer: 'J.K. Rowling',
  singer: 'Beyonce',
  politician: 'A. Merkel'
};

let b = a;
delete a.politician;

console.log(b); //здесь также нет politicaian
```

Почему тогда здесь все работает немного по-другому? По тому же принципу `prototype` является одним объектом, поэтому изменения должны быть везде (по двум ссылкам).

```js
let userInfo = {
    name: 'Kira',
    surname: 'Li',
    age: 25,
    country: 'USA',
    city: 'LA'
};

let food = {
    fruit: 'apple',
    vegetable: 'cabbage',
    pastry: 'bun',
    drink: 'water'
};

function Constructor() {};
Constructor.prototype = userInfo;
let obj = new Constructor;
Constructor.prototype = food; //произошло переприсвоение

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)); //все также userInfo
```

А вот здесь, например, изменение происходит. Почему?

```js
let userInfo = {
        name: 'Kira',
        surname: 'Li',
        age: 25,
        country: 'USA',
        city: 'LA'
    };

    let food = {
        fruit: 'apple',
        vegetable: 'cabbage',
        pastry: 'bun',
        drink: 'water'
    };

    function Constructor() {};
    Constructor.prototype = userInfo;
    let obj = new Constructor;
    Constructor.prototype.name = 'Klara'; //произошло переприсвоение

    console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));
```

Почему так? Почему в некоторых случаях происходит изменение объекта, а в некоторых нет?

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле всё соответствует присвоению по ссылке.

```js
function Constructor() {};
Constructor.prototype = userInfo;
let obj = new Constructor;
Constructor.prototype = food; //произошло переприсвоение
```

Можно представить как:

```js
const obj1 = { a: { b: 1 } }; // Это наш конструктор с прототипом в "a".
const obj2 = { c: obj1.a }; // Это создание экземпляра с ссылкой на прототип.

// obj2.c присвоено значение obj1.a,
// но по сути присвоена ссылка на { b: 1 }
// obj2.c больше не связано с obj1.a, но связано с { b: 1 }

obj1.a = { d: 2 };

// obj1.a теперь ссылается на { d: 2 }
// но obj2.c по-прежнему ссылается на { b: 1 }

console.log(obj2.c); // { b: 1 }
```